# Wamp server won't run the localhost project but run the localhost/phpmyadmin.I face this issue after install the SQL server

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wamp

I changed the port **80** to **81**. When I enter the url **localhost:81/test/** it automatically redirect to **localhost/test/** and show the below error but **localhost:81/phpmyadmin** is working

As you see in the screen shot

Requested URL      http://localhost:80/test/
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\

Request URl automatically take localhost:80 instead of localhost:81
Physical path also wrong. it should take this "C:\wamp64\htdocs\test"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlG90.jpg)

Comment: Is your physical path working ?

Comment: Nope, I copy my site to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ . but it won't work. still face the same issue.

Comment: Please check your folder name , I think it contains some more characters than test .

Comment: Did you use the wampmanager menus to change the port? My guess is you did not change everything required to move the port successfully

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:81/folder' );
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:81/folder' );